# Auto download files to my computer

Tags: windows-7, download-manager, file-download

I'm looking for a Windows 7 program that will be able to download around 1000 files when I give the urls. These are PDF files

```
http://www.ticaretsicil.gov.tr/gazetepdfgoster.php?sayi=8206&sayfa=1
http://www.ticaretsicil.gov.tr/gazetepdfgoster.php?sayi=8206&sayfa=2
http://www.ticaretsicil.gov.tr/gazetepdfgoster.php?sayi=8206&sayfa=3
http://www.ticaretsicil.gov.tr/gazetepdfgoster.php?sayi=8206&sayfa=4
...
http://www.ticaretsicil.gov.tr/gazetepdfgoster.php?sayi=8206&sayfa=672
```

A governmental newspaper with 672 pages for Decembr 3, 2012.

And I have to repeat this for few other days ranging from mid november to end december.

And because you have to be logged in, the program should remember the cookies. Do you know any such Windows 7 application?

Comment: We don't really do software recommendations here at Superuser.

Answer (score 4):

For Linux, wget works great... and it appears that there is a version for Windows, too.

[wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)

Comment: Thanks but I prefer PHP over wget. Both are not user firendly.

Answer (score 1):

If they're on a web site you can use [Down Them All](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) on Firefox.

If they're not then I'd suggest wget and a short script.